# Некорректное сохранение данных из формы в базу

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

Есть приложение Spring+Hibernate+DerbyDB. Сервер TomCat 8.0.32.
Проблема с кодировкой русскоязычных символов при сохранении данных в базу.
С формы уходят данные и сохраняются в кодировке ISO-8859-1. В приложении установлена кодировка UTF-8, также в UTF-8 созданы все .jsp-файлы.
Если создать запись в базе без приложения(напрямую, например через консоль) русскоязычные символы отображаются корректно.
В файл server.xml сервера TomCat в  добавлял параметр URIEncoding="UTF-8", он не помог, данные по-прежнему сохраняются в некорректной кодировке.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, что означает "*В приложении установлена кодировка UTF-8*", должно быть сделано так на всех `JSP` страницах:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Попробуйте также добавить веб-фильтр, выполняющий следующее действие:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
throws ServletException
{
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```