# Как передать параметр через GET-запрос на кириллице?

Tags: java, кодировка, java-ee, form, get

Добрый день! Возникла проблема, реализовываю строку поиска по списку, и при передаче параметра, значение которого в кириллице, через форму, которая передает через метод get, значение отображаются не корректно.

Вот как я это делаю: jsp-страница, с которой происходит передача параметра

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="controller" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="findPatient" />
        <h4>
            <fmt:message key="find_patient" />
        </h4>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="fullName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <fmt:message key="search" />
            </button>
        </div>
</form>
```

В сервлете, который принимает параметр:

```
String fullName = URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("fullName"), "utf-8");
LOG.trace("Request parameter: fullName --> " + fullName);
```

Лог-журнал:

```
[TRACE] CommandAccessFilter(isAllow): 77 - Filter             uricommand=findPatient&fullName=%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9
[TRACE] CommandAccessFilter(isAllow): 93 - Role in session ADMIN
[TRACE] CommandAccessFilter(isAllow): 98 - uri contains: false
[DEBUG] CommandAccessFilter(doFilter): 57 - Filter finished
[TRACE]     Controller(doGet): 35 - doGet method
[DEBUG]     Controller(process): 51 - Controller starts
[TRACE]     Controller(process): 55 - Request parameter: command -->     findPatient
[TRACE]     Controller(process): 59 - Obtained command -->     ua.nure.martseniuk.SummaryTask4.web.commands.FindPatientCommand@4fa7f0cb
command=[findPatient]
fullName=[?°?????µ??????]
[DEBUG] FindPatientCommand(execute): 32 - Commands starts
[TRACE] FindPatientCommand(execute): 36 - Request parameter: fullName -->     %C3%90%C2%B0%C3%91%C2%80%C3%91%C2%81%C3%90%C2%B5%C3%90%C2%BD%C3%90%C2%B8%C3%90%C2%B9
```

Страница, на которой происходит поиск и с которой отправляется форма настроена в кодировке utf-8

Файл server.xml:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               useBodyEncodingForURI="false"
    />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      </Realm>


      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("fullName"), "utf-8");` - зачем вы кодируете-то?

Comment: пытался с помощью енкодера решить эту проблему, без него так же

Comment: Попробуйте это решение: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524714/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83/524826#524826

Comment: так как мое приложение работает с кириллицой, то фильтр для кодировки уже поставлен, и для всех страниц поставлена кодировка utf-8, что я написал в вопроса

Comment: проблема в том, что когда я передаю параметр через гет(параметр на кириллице), он соответственно кодируется в %D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9, что является правильным, но потом приходя в контроллер он переводиться вот в такое: fullName=[?°?????µ??????]

Comment: В качестве контейнера используете tomcat?

Comment: да, для контейнера сервлетов использую томкат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно в конфигурации Tomcat задать для `<Connector>` атрибут `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` (см. http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2). Это заставит Tomcat декодировать все части URL (в том числе GET-параметры) с помощью UTF-8.

**UPD:**
Так как вы используете Eclipse, всё немного сложнее. Говорят ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485760/eclipse-with-tomcat-eclipse-modifies-server-xml), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233263/eclipse-modify-server-xml-each-time-run-the-project-run-run-on-server)), Eclipse либо перезаписывает `server.xml` каждый раз при запуске веб-приложения, либо переопределяет его (зависит настройки сервера в Eclipse). Я не использую Eclipse, но насколько я понял, есть такие способы сохранить ваши модификации:

- В Eclipse удалить Tomcat из панели Servers; затем внести нужные изменения в `server.xml`; затем обратно добавить Tomcat в Eclipse. Это создаст конфигурацию на основе изменённого `server.xml`.
- В папке `{workspace}/Servers/` или `{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/` найти конфигурацию Tomcat и внести изменения прямо туда (но эта конфигурация может в какой-то момент измениться без уведомления).

Comment: к сожалению все также, в server.xml для <Connector>  задал указанный атрибут и также указал useBodyEncodingForURI="true".

Comment: `useBodyEncodingForURI` это зря, попробуйте без него.

Comment: попробовал без него, также как и было, в лог-журнал выводит крякозябры

Comment: Попробуйте ещё 2 вещи: 1) выставить явно `useBodyEncodingForURI="false"`, 2) там, где вы делаете `request.getParameter(...)`, вывести в лог значение `request.getClass()` - может, кто-то подменяет `request` на свой кривой wrapper.

Comment: 1) поставил явно useBodyEncodingForURI="false", ничего не изменилось; 2) вывел в лог: `FindPatientCommand(execute): 38 - Request parameter: class --> class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade`

Comment: А вы точно у того Connector-а установили атрибуты? Можете добавить `server.xml` в текст вопроса? У вас только один tomcat? Как вы запускаете своё приложение?

Comment: да, добавил в коннектор с портом 8080, который я использую; запускаю приложение через eclipse.

Comment: у меня только один томкат

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вы уверены, что страница в браузере отображается в кодировке utf-8? Скорее всего проблема именно в этом. Поэтому и на сервер передается параметр в соответствующей кодировке, а Вы пытаетесь прочитать в utf-8. Проверьте и добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: страница, с которой я отправляю в форму отображается в utf-8